# Git installed through gitosys doesn't (probably) honor HOME environment variable when run from Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm trying to use git from Cygwin, but here's what I see:

```
$ git clone ssh://git-repo/some/repository
Cloning into 'repository'...
ssh: git-repo-actual-host-name.com: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The message is obviously false because:

```
$ echo "$HOME"
/home/wvxvw
$ cat $HOME/.ssh/config
Host git-repo
 HostName git-repo-actual-host-name.com
 User wvxvw
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ ls $HOME/.ssh
config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Any ideas what is going wrong / how to help it?

**EDIT**:

Same info, but less "obfuscated":

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host tlv-git
 HostName tlv-git.host.com
 User WINDOMAIN\\wvxvw
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

$ ssh tlv-git
ssh: Could not resolve hostname tlv-git: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

$ ssh tlv-git.host.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

This is what happens if I then try to clone some repository:

```
$ git clone ssh://tlv-git/repo
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

But I have `ssh-agent` installed, so if I do:

```
$ eval $( ssh-agent )
$ ssh-add
$ git clone ssh://tlv-git/repo
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

But if I provide the user name, then it works...

```
$ git clone ssh://WINDOMAIN\\wvxvw@tlv-git/repo
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the user you're connecting to in the ssh:// line.

Comment: Have you seen the message `ssh: some.host.com: no address associated with name`? It expects a hostname to be set.

Comment: @wvxvw You need to provide a `HostName` directive. `Host` is used to create an alias, but you also have to define where that alias points to.

Comment: Can you give the url you are using as close as possible? Either the hostname doesn't exist, or the url is malformed

Comment: what is the output of `ssh git-repo`?

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be `git-repo:/some/repository`, and the user un the ~/.ssh/config is usually one dedicated to gitosis installation (`git`, not `wvxvw`)

These days (2018, 5 years later), if the same setup needed to be repeated, it would use:

- [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), not gitosis.
- [OpenSSH directly in Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/22/openssh-in-windows-10/), not Cygwin.